Fetch top 3 students from each subject using SQL
I have 2 tables.Students and Subjects:
CREATE TABLE Student (
    student_id NUMBER,
    student_name VARCHAR
);

CREATE TABLE Subject (
    subject_id NUMBER,
    student_id NUMBER,
    subject_name VARCHAR,
    marks NUMBER    
);

I have added below data
INSERT INTO Student
VALUES (1001, 'Sanjay Naik');
INSERT INTO Student
VALUES (1002, 'Rohit Sharma');
INSERT INTO Student
VALUES (1003, 'Virat Kolhi');
INSERT INTO Student
VALUES (1004, 'Nitish Kumar Reddy');

INSERT INTO Subject
VALUES (1,1001, 'Maths',72);
INSERT INTO Subject
VALUES (2,1001, 'English',84);
INSERT INTO Subject
VALUES (1,1002, 'Maths',79);
INSERT INTO Subject
VALUES (2,1002, 'English',94);
INSERT INTO Subject
VALUES (1,1003, 'Maths',65);
INSERT INTO Subject
VALUES (2,1003, 'English',89);
INSERT INTO Subject
VALUES (1,1004, 'Maths',54);
INSERT INTO Subject
VALUES (2,1004, 'English',51);

How to fetch top 3 students based on marks obtained in every subject? Like fetch top 3 students in both english and maths subject.
I tried following ,
SELECT * FROM Student
INNER JOIN Subject
ON Student.student_id = Subject.student_id
ORDER BY Subject.marks DESC;

Above query gives students by the order of their marks scored in both subjects. If i add LIMIT 3 it will fetch top 3 whereas i want top 3 students in both english and maths.

With every top n question you must know what to do in case of ties. If there were only four math students with the scores 50, 50, 60, 60, would you show 2, 3 or 4 students?

I've removed the java tag. This question has nothing to do with Java.

Ideally it would be helpful if you could have shared the expected results as well.
You could achieve top 3 students for each subject like below :
1.CTE ranked_students combines the subject name, student name, and marks. RANK()  analytic function assigns a rank to each row within each subject_name partition, ordered by marks in descending order. The highest marks get rank 1.
2.rnk <= 3 filters the results to include only the top 3 students for each subject based on their ranks.
Fiddle
WITH ranked_students AS (
    SELECT 
        su.subject_name,
        st.student_name,
        su.marks,
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY su.subject_name ORDER BY su.marks DESC) AS rnk
    FROM 
        Subject su
    JOIN 
        Student st ON su.student_id = st.student_id
)
SELECT 
    subject_name,
    student_name,
    marks
FROM 
    ranked_students
WHERE 
    rnk <= 3
ORDER BY 
    subject_name, rnk;

Output



SUBJECT_NAME
STUDENT_NAME
MARKS




English
Rohit Sharma
94


English
Virat Kolhi
89


English
Sanjay Naik
84


Maths
Rohit Sharma
79


Maths
Sanjay Naik
72


Maths
Virat Kolhi
65




This worked.Thanks @samhita

Glad you found it helpful:) @SanjayNaik

Use RANK function (or maybe DENSE_RANK depending on what behavior you need in case of students with exactly the same marks on top). You can check details in documentation about using the RANK function. Something like:
WITH top_students AS (
  SELECT 
    subject_name,
    student_id,
    marks,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY subject_id ORDER BY marks DESC) AS marks_rank
    FROM Subject)
    
SELECT
  subject_name,
  student_name,
  marks 
FROM top_students t
INNER JOIN Student s
ON t.student_id = s.student_id 
WHERE marks_rank < 4;

